# Embedding CiviCRM Event form in an Iframe

Tags: forms

I used to be able to embed CiviCRM forms in Iframes without issue. 
Recently, I haven't been successful and getting this error:

Refused to display 'http://website.com/civicrm/event/register?id=2' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: Is this an iframe on the same domain or a different one?

Comment: Different domain

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you're running into cross-domain iframe issues.  I think this question falls outside the scope of this Stack Exchange unless there's something CiviCRM-specific about the issue.  You can search for "iframe some origin policy" to see what's involved in cross-domain iframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal core is now protected against clickjacking by default:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2735873

You can install Security Kit module -> and then add specific allow-from domains.